# Python tool to find meaningful pairs of words in a document

Tags: python, nltk, nlp

I'm writing a program that gathers tweets from Twitter, and evaluates the text to find trending topics. I'm planning on using NLTK to stem the terms and do some other operations on the data.

What I need is a tool that can determine if two adjacent words in a tweet should be treated as a single term. For example, if "fake news" is trending on Twitter, I don't want to treat those two words as different. Another example, if everyone is tweeting about 'Computer Science', it wouldn't make sense to treat computer and science as two different terms since they refer to the same topic. Does a tool exist that can find such terms?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a dataset called 'bi-gram', which will give you a rating of how often a given pair of words seen together (i.e. frequency) in a given language. Higher the frequency, the more likely that the pair is a term.

For example, take a look at [COCA](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) for a searchable and downloadable corpus. Google has a similar dataset. There are 3-grams and 4-grams, generally called *n-grams*.

In the COCA dataset, *computer science* has a frequency rating of 1604; *fake news* has 828, and *apple car* has 2. So you need to decide the threshold frequency to accept the pair as a term.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem to play with, assuming there's not already a lexicon of meaningful compound words that you could leverage. And I'd love to see "computer science" as a trending topic.

Let's take the approach that we know nothing about compound words in English, whether "stop sign" is as meaningfully distinct from "stop" and "sign" as 
"does better" is from "does" and "better"

Breaking it down, you want to build a process that:

1. Identifies co-located pairs
2. Drops any that are clearly not related as compound words (ie parts of    speech, proper names or punctuation)
3. Saves candidate pairs
4. Analyzes candidate pairs for frequency
5. Teaches your system to look for the most valuable candidate pairs

Is that an accurate description?
If so, I think the tool you ask for would be in (4) or (5). For 4), consider the Associative Rule in Python's Orange library as a start. You could also use TF-IDF from scikit-learn. For 5) you could expose the output from 4) as a list, set or dictionary of strings with counts.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a set of special combinations and pre-process your phrase before tokenization:

```
import nltk

def preprocess_text(original_text):
    specials = {"computer vision": "computer_vision",
                "fake news": "fake_news"}
    out = original_text.lower()
    for k in specials:
        out = out.replace(k, specials[k])
    return out

def main():
    txt = preprocess_text("Computer vision has nothing to do wiht fake news")
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(txt)
    nltk.FreqDist(tokens).tabulate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It would be better to have a specialized tokenization though.